# Flask - Retrieve Steam ID

Tags: html, flask, steam-web-api

I'm working on a Flask project and would like users to be able to connect one or more Steam accounts to their profile on the website. The user is not logging into my website with their Steam account, they are just registering a Steam account to a pre-existing profile on my site, so I'm not sure if I should be using OpenID or not.

I would like for there to be some way for the user to enter their Steam username, be shown a corresponding account, and register the account to their profile. Or alternatively, there is a button that takes the user to a Steam Login page, which redirects back to my website after logging in and passing back the needed data. I'm not picky how, I just need to somehow get the ID associated with a Steam account.

Everything I've found so far has been for logging into a website using a Steam account. I assume the process would be similar, and maybe easier, to just get back an ID based on user input, but so far I've had no luck.

Thanks for your help